# Learn/build ios on phonegap for free on windows

Tags: cordova

I am trying to learn phonegap, and I want to build/learn to make an app on ios with windows OS. I read some blogs, tuts, but it seems I have to pay $99/year? I don't want to pay trying to learn from it. Can anyone have some resource? or is it possible to do it for free(for now just to learn)?

Comment: you can learn for free reading the tutorials online, But you CANNOT practice what you learn for free. You need a MAC PC minimum and an account on Apples App store. You may get some discount if you are a student or if you know any student you is willing to help you out. For this search Apple's developer forum for student account.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is not build the apps with Cordova, but build the app with some cloud service. Only notice that there are some issues with some plugins on those cloud services.

For example if you want to build an IOS app, you could use the Adobe PhoneGap cloud build, located at http://build.phonegap.com. But you can only use the plugins that are on the site http://plugins.phonegap.com. You can't use all the plugins on http://plugins.cordova.io.

You could also use Telerik for example to build in the cloud (30 day free trial). With Telerik it is possible to build for IOS and also use plugins from http://plugins.cordova.io.

Problem I am facing now is that when you use any cloud building solution and one of your plugins needs some tweaks in xCode you are stuck. So to my believe the best way to go is make sure to have a Mac and xCode and build is yourselve.